# Detect if data in form is changed or not

Tags: angular, forms

In angular app, I am using template driven form (not reactive form). I want to show a popup to user, if user closes the form in which he has entered some data.

User will be allowed to close the form if he doesn't enter anything inside form.

In reactive form we can subscribe to `form’s value Changes observable` and detect if form is changed or not.

How will I do this inside component in template driven one.  `form.dirty` can only be checked inside template not inside component file

Comment: Before I will try to answer this: Why are your using a template driven form?

Comment: i found it easy to use compared to reactive forms.. we shouldn't use template driven ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can equally subscribe to template driven forms:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="myForm.valid && submitForm()">
  <input type="text" id="name"
   required
   [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name">
</form>
```

And in the .ts:

```
formChanged:boolean 
@ViewChild("myForm", { static: true }) myForm: NgForm
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(c => {
            this.formChanged = true; 
    });
}

closeForm(){
    if(this.formChanged){
        ...show message
    }else 
        ...close
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Template Form is a old one .Angular team recommending to use reactive form. since it simple and powerful than template driven forms.
Ok For your problem use template ref variable like
eg: #templateVar ="ngForm"

use the templatevar in component to get reference to your form

Comment: use like below in html
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #templateVar ="ngForm">
use like below in comp
@ViewChild('templateVar ',{  read: false, static: false })templateVar : NgForm;